# simple encryption in C# and VB returns different results

Tags: c#, vb.net, encryption, password-encryption

I have an application that encrypts data which is written in VB. There is another application that uses the same data. Encryption code is the same but it returns different result in some cases. Below are the encryption code in VB and C#.

=================================== VB CODE =================================

```
Dim s1 As String = ""
Dim i As Integer

If value = 0 Then value = 52

For i = 0 To s.Length - 1
   s1 += Chr(Asc(s.Substring(i, 1)) Xor value)
Next

Return s1
```

=================================== C# CODE =================================

```
string Result = ""; 

int i = 0;

   try
   {
    if (value == 0)
        value = 52;

    char[] chars = s.ToCharArray();

    for (i = 0; i <= chars.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        Result += (char)((int)(chars[i]) ^ value);
    }


}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
}

return Result;
```

Comment: I can't see any references to encryption libraries, are you rolling your own encryption? That's a very bad thing.

Comment: Why cant you just reference the c# library rather than duplicating encryption code?

Comment: I'd call this obfuscation, not encryption. And why the hell are you obfuscating passwords?

Comment: My dream is to have to find a day a bank whith such an encription :)

Comment: What you are doing is **NOT** encryption. It is an obfuscation, scrabmle, or cypher, which is not at all the same.  Additionally, even real encryption would be **wrong** here. A password should be _hashed_ using a cryptographic algorithm (there are non-cryptographic algorithms like md5, which should be avoided), **never** encrypted.

Answer (score 4):

The VB.NET Chr() and Asc() functions are legacy functions that are compatible with the way early versions of Visual Basic treated characters.  They assume 8-bit encoding in the system code page.  Use the Unicode compatible ChrW() and AscW() functions instead.  Or use Encoding.Default.GetBytes() if you need the C# code to produce the same result as the VB.NET code.

Comment: Its not my code, we have to write a new application that is based on an old application that was written in VB.net. Both these apps uses the same database :(

Comment: I cant make any changes in the VB code, I just have to comply the so called encryption. Anyways Encoding.Default is not available in C# rather it has Encoding.UTF8, Unicode etc...

Comment: Encoding.Default has been available in .NET since version 1.0.  I cannot guess why you have a problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this VB Code:

```
Dim Result As String = ""

Dim i As Integer = 0

Try
    If value = 0 Then
        value = 52
    End If

    Dim chars As Char() = s.ToCharArray()

    For i = 0 To chars.Length - 1
        Result += CChar(CInt(chars(i)) Xor value)


    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error")
End Try

Return Result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using (byte) or (short) instead of (int) when you cast it. That may work!